# Send String from Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android

I try to pass a String from an Activity to a Fragment. As you can see I am using an if statement to prevent the app from crashing. The Toast message always shows 'Bundle null'. How can i prevent the bunde from being null?

Activity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SetttingsFragment())
            .commit();


    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundleSettings.putString("my_bundle_key", "Bundle");     
    SetttingsFragment setttingsFragment = new SetttingsFragment();
    setttingsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Fragment:

```
public class SetttingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat  {
@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String rootKey) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if(bundle != null){
        String bundleString = bundle.getString("my_bundle_key");
        Log.i("my_bundle_key", bundleString);           
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bundle null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: add Bundle value before this line  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SetttingsFragment())
            .commit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are setting the bundle to a fragment variable that you are not using

1. create bundle
2. create fragment
3. set bundle in fragment
4. show fragment

this is the way you need to pass the arguments in fragment

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("my_bundle_key", "Bundle");     
        settingsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    }
    else {
        settingsFragment.setArguments(savedInstanceState);
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(android.R.id.content, settingsFragment)
        .commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your activity you are creating two objects of fragment, second object where you are doing `setargument` is not attached to the view and not in use. Your fragment should be attached to the view like this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundleSettings.putString("my_bundle_key", "Bundle");     
SetttingsFragment setttingsFragment = new SetttingsFragment();
setttingsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(android.R.id.content, setttingsFragment)
        .commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call Bundle before calling `fragment` like this following:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundleSettings.putString("my_bundle_key", "Bundle");     
        SetttingsFragment setttingsFragment = new SetttingsFragment();
        setttingsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, setttingsFragment)
                .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
From Activity you send data with intent as:

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
Fragmentclass obj = new Fragmentclass();
obj .setArguments(bundle);
```

In Fragment onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Activity

```
AbcFragment fragment = AbcFragment .newInstance(**Value**);
               getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.layout_container, fragment)
                        .commit();
```

> In Fragment

```
public static AbcFragment newInstance(String Value) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putString("Value", Value);

        AbcFragment fragment = new AbcFragment ();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it as arguments with Fragments and then can start fragment transactions to start the fragment.key used here is "input" and Here the example -

```
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("input", "dummy string args");
   MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
   mapFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and the receive the arguments i.e input inside fragment , use it like -

```
String data =  getArguments().getString("input")
```